# What is the Key code for this key from Android Keyboard for Appium scripting?

Tags: python, android, appium, appium-android

I am trying to send an SMS with Python and Appium. When I type the phone number, I need to press the blue key on the bottom right corner (see screenshot) to validate the phone and then to write the SMS.

I thought to use "Keys.ENTER", but it transform the phone number I previously typed in some kind of cross inside a box (see screenshot) .

If I press by hand the blue validation key on the bottom right corner of the keyboard, it validates the phone and I can start to type my SMS. So obviously "Keys.ENTER" is not this blue key.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
search_text_field.click()
p_driver.implicitly_wait(10)
time.sleep(random.uniform(1.1, 2.1))
search_text_field.clear()
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 0.8))
search_text_field.send_keys(phone_number)
# For sms, we can't check if we found element. We need to press the Key "VALIDATE" or "ENTER"
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 0.8))
search_text_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 0.8))
```

Does anyone can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try with press

> driver.press_keycode(66)